# mongodb query different array have different condition

Tags: mongodb

I have the following datas.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc123"),
    "device_id": "A001",
    "A_status": "VALID",
    "B_status": "VALID"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc223"),
    "device_id": "A003",
    "A_status": "EXPIRED",
    "B_status": "VALID"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc323"),
    "device_id": "B001",
    "A_status": "EXPIRED",
    "B_status": "VALID"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc423"),
    "device_id": "B002",
    "A_status": "VALID",
    "B_status": "EXPIRED"
},]
```

I have two different device_id list:
a_list = ["A001", "A003", ...]
b_list = ["B001", "B002", ...]

a_list need match A_status is VALID, b_list need match A_status is VALID.

I want to find deive_id in a_list and A_status is VALID, deive_id in b_list and B_status is VALID,
so I will get following correct data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc123"),
    "device_id": "A001",
    "A_status": "VALID",
    "B_status": "VALID"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc323"),
    "device_id": "B001",
    "A_status": "EXPIRED",
    "B_status": "VALID"
}
```

How do I execute once query and get the answer?
Or have to separate queries for different conditions?

Comment: MongoDB has `$or` and `$and` query operators which can be used within the `db.collection.find()` method _filter_. You can build your query using these.

Comment: Sorry, I update my question.
If I only have device_id, and device_id is no rules, means it may like: "ddbe4b9f-c999-41d4-3051-39b1a43e95fb", "6a611738-2748-4660-9820-ffdb43657d3a"
Will this achieve my desired result?

Comment: You can query by using a list of values with the [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

Comment: @prasad_ 
yes, I resolved my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$or`

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      A_status: "VALID",
      device_model: {
        $in: [
          "A001",
          "A003"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      B_status: "VALID",
      device_model: {
        $in: [
          "B001",
          "B002"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k5WlD5nsVge)

Comment: Thanks, I use this way, it actually resolved my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to get different data from MongoDB. To get model AXXX and A_status is VALID you can use this query.

```
{
    device_model: { $regex :/^A/},
    A_status: 'VALID'
}
```

To get BXXX and B_status is VALID you can use:

```
{
    device_model: { $regex :/^B/},
    B_status: 'VALID'
}
```

It may be useful to take a look into mongo regex [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).